# Compare two dates based on year-month, taking no notice of day

Tags: java, date, compare, hql, date-comparison

I need to be able to compare two dates, only based on the year and the month (i.e. without taking notice of the day), and that in JAVA and HQL.

Let's say I need to check if `d1` is less than or equals `d2`. Here is what I tried:

JAVA

```
calendar.setTime(d1);
int y1 = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int m1 = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
calendar.setTime(d2);
int y2 = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int m2 = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
return y1 <= y2 && m1 <= m2;
```

HQL

```
select item from Item item
where year(item.d1) <= year(:d2)
and month(item.d1) <= month(:d2)
```

The algorithm is the same in the both pieces of code above, but it's wrong:

- `2011-10 LTE 2012-09` should return `true` but will return `false` because `2011 < 2012` but `10 !< 09`

If I use a `OR` instead of a `AND`, it's still wrong:

- `2013-01 LTE 2012-05` should return `false` but will return `true` because `2013 !< 2012` but `01 < 05`

So, how should I process? Please, I need it for JAVA and HQL.

Comment: FYI, I suspect the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class may be of use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.

```
select item from Item item
where year(item.d1) < year(:d2) or
     (year(item.d1) = year(:d2)
      and month(item.d1) <= month(:d2))
```

Same for Java:

```
y1 < y2 || (y1 == y2 && m1 <= m2)
```

You could keep second check as `y1 <= y2` but it would be a little redundant.